# Dynamically Set Print Area for excel template

Tags: excel

I am developing a Silverlight application. I have to export a excel. But my client wants to set the print area dynamically. So right now Infragistics doesn't provide any option to set the Print Area dynamically. So I want set the Print Area in Excel template itself. So is there any way can we set the Print Area Dynamically in Excel and save it.

Please help me Guys...

Many Thanks
Anil Kumar

Answer (score 1):

When you set the Print Area in Excel, a worksheet-scoped name is created called Print_Area.  You can modify this name (just keep it worksheet-scoped) just like any other name.  If, for example, you want to your print area to start in A1 and extend to column E for as many entries as you have in column A, you could set the Print_Area name to

```
=Sheet1!$A$1:INDEX(Sheet1!$E:$E,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A),1)
```

You don't say what drives the dynamics of the print area, so this is just an example.  You'll need to use a formula that suits your logic for your particular case.

Comment: I've always written code to do this.  Never occurred to just modify the range definition.  Great tip!